# Application of Weak Law of Large Number

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

Let $_1,_2, … , _$ be a sequence of independent random variables with $(_ = 4^) =
(_ = −4^) = \frac12$. Let $_ = _1 + _2 + ⋯ + _$. Determine for which $ > 0$, if any, that the $P(\frac{1}{}|S_n|≥ )$ does not converge to $0$. Why does this result not contradict with the weak law of large numbers?

To determine for which $ > 0$, I tried to use chebyshev's inequality, $P(\frac{1}{}|S_n|≥ )≤\frac {Var(S_n)}{^2} = \frac {Var(X_1+X_2+...+X_n)}{^2} = \frac{Var(X_1)+Var(X_2)+...+Var(X_n)}{^2}$ since $_1,_2, … , _$ are independent, then I took $0≤\frac{Var(X_1)+Var(X_2)+...+Var(X_n)}{^2}≤1$ and find the range of $\epsilon$ , is that correct? and how to relate the result with WLLN?

Comment: To use weak law of large number you need independence and identical distribution. But the distribution of $X_n$ depends on $n$, so the distributions are not identical.

Comment: Chebychev's inequality cannot be used to find the exact set of permissible values of $\epsilon$.

Comment: if that's the case, then I have no idea on how to determine for which ε>0...

Comment: Perhaps note that $|X_n|$ attains a value so large (compared to previous $X_k$, $k < n$) that in fact value of $|S_n|$ is, in magnitude, close to $X_n$.  Then $|S_n|/n$ should always tend to $+\infty$. How this does not contradict the weak law of large numbers is, I guess, dependent on the particular formulation of said theorem that you want to use.

Comment: @BartoszMalman Nice comment! I am curious to know what happens if $4^{n}$ is replaced by $2^{n}$. Your argument works only for $r^{n}$ with $r>2$, I beleive.

Comment: @geetha290km Indeed this is more interesting. If $X_k = +-2^k$, then maybe one should consider that each time $X_k$ and $X_{k+1}$ attain a value with different sign, then some lower bound on $|S_{k+1}|$ is ensured.

Comment: I think I have settled this. The conclusion holds iff $r\le 1$. @BartoszMalman

Comment: Yeah, I agree. We have $S_{n+1}/(n+1) = (n/(n+1))S_n/n + X_{n+1}/(n+1)$, so that $S_n/n$ cannot stay in a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ if $X_{n+1}/(n+1)$ grows to infinity.